# implement people picker in Android

Tags: android-layout, android-widget, android

This is quite a challenge. I am trying to start implementing the People Picker in Android. This is common to the iOS only.

Please refer to this link to get the idea of what I am trying to achieve:

[User Interaction: Prompting for and Displaying Data](http://developer.apple.com/library/iOS/#documentation/ContactData/Conceptual/AddressBookProgrammingGuideforiPhone/Chapters/UI_Controllers.html)

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android/android-essentials-using-the-contact-picker/